# Why are Asgardian ships so huge?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Asgardians have only one being in a very large ship. Why didn't they make their ship small enough for maneuverability, stealth, and easy-enough to defend when breached?

Or just make their ship big like a 747 for cargo-capacity? Apparently, Asgard does not need personnel, or lodging, nor dining. They basically have large hallways making it difficult for the Tau'ri to defend the ship while being breached by Replicators.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually, Asgardian spaceships do have a crew, as is mentioned in **[season 3, episode 22: Nemesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemesis_%28Stargate_SG-1%29%5C)**.

Short transcript (O'Neill viewing the first recording made by Thor):

> **Thor:**
>
> 'During the battle this ship became infested by the technology. The replicators accessed the computer which contained information about your planet and plotted a course here. **The crew was transported off the ship.** I destroyed the outbound transporter technology to prevent the replicators from escaping.'

This scene occurs roughly 9 minutes into this episode.

Comment: But really, all throughout the season, we never see thor or the other commanders have a crew. They dont neccessarily need it since one asgard can control a ship from the control room.

Comment: @Sid While the lack of visible crew may be due to budget issues with the actual show, I can tell you that ships rarely run the bare minimum when it comes to crew members. While the bare minimum is certainly possible (read: skeleton crews), it is not nearly efficient.

Comment: to the point where asgard ships can be smaller. Like the one the ancients used. small but deadly :D